# Shared Element Transition not working Java Android

Tags: java, android, shared-element-transition

I'm trying to implement a shared element transition between a fragment that has a Recyclerview and another fragment let say something like a Detail Fragment.

The fragments are:

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_staff"
    android:name="main.staff.StaffFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_staff"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_staff">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_nav_staff_to_nav_user_profile"
        app:destination="@id/nav_user_profile">
        <argument
            android:name="selectedUser"
            app:argType="string" />
    </action>
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_user_profile"
    android:name="main.staff.UserProfileFragment"
    android:label="@string/profile"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_user_profile" />
```

In the recycler view adapter I'm setting the element transition name like:

```
public void setBinding(UserModel model, OnItemClicked onUserClick) {
        binding.setModel(model);
        binding.executePendingBindings();

        binding.coworkerImage.setTransitionName(model.getUid());

        binding.itemContainer.setOnClickListener(v -> onUserClick.onItemClick(binding.coworkerImage, model.getUid()));
    }
```

Then in the detail fragment in the onCreate method I'm setting:

```
setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getContext()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move));
```

then in the onViewCreated method of the detail fragment I'm setting the transition name of the image like:

```
userViewModel.getCurrentUser(selectedUid).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), model -> {

        USER = model;

        binding.userAvatar.setTransitionName(USER.getUid());

        binding.setModel(USER);
    });
```

In the main fragment when I click an item of the recycler view the transition animation is not happening, I did everything according to the documentation:

```
private void onItemClick(View v, String uid) {

    FragmentNavigator.Extras extras = new FragmentNavigator.Extras.Builder()
            .addSharedElement(v, v.getTransitionName())
            .build();

    StaffFragmentDirections.ActionNavStaffToNavUserProfile action =
            StaffFragmentDirections.actionNavStaffToNavUserProfile(uid);

    navController.navigate(action, extras);
}
```

The idea is: when I click an item in the recycler view it should open the detail fragment with shared element transition.